# RelativeLayout won't fill the whole screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have three `RelativeLauouts` in a `LinearLayout` and I can't make it fill the whole screen on my emulator?? What is the problem?

Here is my `xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/letteord"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/letteord"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Let"
        android:id="@+id/letteOrdbutton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:background="#a4000000"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/normaleord"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/normaleord"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Normal"
        android:id="@+id/normaleOrdbutton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#a4000000"
        android:textSize="50dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/svaereord"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/svaereord"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Svær"
        android:id="@+id/svaereOrdbutton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#a4000000" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried changing the layout with and height but it still won't fill the whole screen as you can see on this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: is this a fragment or activity? do you have a padding in your activities layout?

Comment: it's a fragment with no padding

Comment: But the main activity layout does have padding

Comment: and that's your problem. Remove padding from your activity.

Comment: yes it was the problem, now it works

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see no paddings or margins in the code above. Is this just a portion of your code in your `xml` file? Check your main activity layout to see if there is any padding or margins. Delete them if there is and it should work fine.